# Amber or yellow lights

Tags: word-usage, colors

What is the difference in usage between amber and yellow, when it is the color of traffic lights or some derived meaning? Is this purely a difference between British English and American English, or does the context matter?

For example, on each side of the Pond, if you're driving, is it an amber light or a yellow light that announces an imminent red light? When indicating a status between red (no go) and green (ok), is the status amber or yellow?

---

**EDIT:** I already know that the UK has amber lights and the US have yellow light, this is not what I am asking here. What I am asking is whether there is more to it than a simple US/UK distinction. How unusual would it be to use the wrong word? Is the usage for traffic lights the same as for derived meanings such as [traffic light rating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_light_rating_system)? What prompted this question was finding that the Wikipedia article on the rating system uses amber — I don't know if this reflects US usage as well, or if this is merely due to the article having been written by a BrE speaker, or if the RAG rating is a purely British notion and AmE speakers would not think to use a red/yellow/green rating system.

Comment: Here in the U.S., I usually hear it referred to as _yellow_, although I have heard _amber_ on occasion.

Comment: In the US, the in-between light is called 'yellow';  'amber' is fossilized sap that ancient insects are embedded in.

Comment: @Mitch There's more to *amber* than 'fossilized sap that ancient insects are embedded in'.

Comment: @Kris: no doubt. likewise 'yellow'. I'm just giving the most superficial feeling of the two words in the US.

Comment: Note that in the US, the traffic light sequence is *green - yellow - red - green*. I don't know about the UK, but in the parts of Europe where they drive on the correct side of the road, the traffic light sequence is *green - yellow - red - red+yellow - green*. Not that any of this makes any difference to what that middle light color is *called*, mind you.

Comment: @Marthaª Not in all the parts of Europe: some have the same sequence as the US, some go G-Y-R-Y-G (yes, the yellow is ambiguous), and there are more variations such as flashing. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_variations_in_traffic_light_signalling_and_operation) for an incomplete list. Not that this is relevant to my question, so we shouldn't be having this question here.

Comment: At least one U.S. agency uses "amber status" in the sense of the question.  The Coast Guard's Operation Risk Management system: http://www.uscg.mil/hq/nsfweb/foscr/ASTFOSCRSeminar/Presentations/Safety/ORM-GAR.pdf

Comment: note that UK *railway* signals show **yellow** aspects

Comment: Yeah, in the US you rarely hear "amber" used to describe a traffic control signal of any kind.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure I've ever heard of *yellow* traffic lights, but here are 65 written instances of ["drove through a **yellow** light"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22drove%20through%20a%20yellow%20light%22).

I assume it's a US/UK difference. To my British ear, ["drove through an **amber** light"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22drove%20through%20an%20amber%20light%22) sounds natural, but there are actually only 7 of them.

Note that ["ran a yellow light"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%20%22ran%20a%20yellow%20light%22) gets 369 hits, against 23 for ["ran an amber light"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ran%20an%20amber%20light%22). That stronger bias I put down to the fact that [ran a red light](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ran%20a%20red%20light&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) is about ten times more common in the US than the UK.

I doubt anyone's choice of colour-word would be influenced by the exact wavelength/frequency of the lights themselves on either side of the Atlantic, but it's worth noting that the UK sequence is [Red, **Red and Amber**, Green, Amber](https://www.bsm.co.uk/traffic-lights), whereas in the US it's just [Red, Green, Yellow](http://forums.pepipoo.com/index.php?showtopic=56725). The colour *amber* is often described as a [reddish or brownish](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/amber) yellow. Perhaps British usage is influenced by the fact that half of all the times we see our "yellow" light, the red one is also on.

---

The [official British "security alert" scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIKINI_state) was headed by *red, amber* until it was replaced in 2006 (by an apparently non-colour-coded scale). The [American equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeland_Security_Advisory_System) has *red, orange* (*yellow* next).

Comment: In the US, the *law* calls it an amber light; the drivers call it a yellow light, or just a "yellow".

Comment: ... and running it is called "squeezing the lemon."

Comment: @Malvolio: That's also the case in the UK [Highway Code](http://www.justcoachdrivers.com/pdf/TheHighwayCode.pdf). For several reasons I suspect proportionately more Americans "run" traffic lights than Brits do. A [former first lady](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081014050654AAyG9nZ) comes to mind.

Comment: It's all a matter of dialect. When I was a kid in the USA back in the 1950s, traffic signals had red, green, and {amber / yellow} lights. Mid-Atlantic dialect (northern and central New Jersey). California calls these lights _yellow_ [link](http://www.dmv.ca.gov/pubs/hdbk/traff_lgts_sgns.htm); New Jersey does too [link](http://www.state.nj.us/mvc/manuals/chap_11_01.html).

Comment: I am British, and I almost always say and hear "yellow" (but obviously understand both).

Comment: Unlike the obvious alternative, the slogan 'Don't be a yellow gambler!' has never really caught on over here in the UK.

Comment: @Billy That's surprising.  When I grew up in the UK, I consistently heard the word "amber".  In fact, I knew that the word "amber" meant "the colour of the middle light in a set of traffic lights" long before I knew that it also referred to a kind of fossilised resin.

Comment: @Pitarou: Strange. It could well be a dialect thing. Or indeed, perhaps 90% of my conversations in which the term has come up have been with my dad (who taught me to drive), and "yellow" happened to be what he uses. Don't know.

Comment: I'm British, and I've *never* heard it called "yellow". And I just asked my colleague next to me what the light is between red and green and he said "amber", too.

Comment: @Billy: where in the UK do you live?  I’ve lived in London, York, and Cambridge, and *amber* was by far the predominant term in all of those places.

Comment: @PLL: Given the upvotes for Malvolio's comment, and the fact that the question was originally closed as GR, I assume this is a pretty consistent US/UK difference. I seem to recall that Americans also don't tend to recognise *avocado* as a "colour". One of those weird things like *Why did the ancient Greeks always refer to the colour of the sea as "wine-dark", rather than some shade of blue?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: oh, I quite agree about the general US/UK difference.  But Billy’s claim suggests that perhaps there are pockets of *yellow* in the UK, which would be interesting.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: and on a side note, re the *wine-dark* question: have you come across the interesting theories about colour categorisation in ancient Greek?  This is discussed very nicely in e.g. Guy Deutscher’s lovely [Through the Language Glass](http://www.amazon.com/Through-Language-Glass-Different-Languages/dp/0312610491).

Comment: @PLL: I've several times heard the proposition that ancient Greeks were colour-blind in that respect. Coincidentally, a few days ago I happened to see here in SE UK the "bluest" sky I can recall in my life - the sheer wonder of which was somewhat tempered by a sinking feeling that maybe this was just another side-effect of global warming...

Comment: @PLL: Liverpool is where I learnt to drive and have spent most of my life. (A short while in Cambridge / London, but I suppose I didn't really have many conversations about yellow lights there...)

Comment: @Malvolio - [Minnesota Statutes](https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/?id=169.06): *Subd. 5.Traffic-control signal.

(a) Whenever traffic is controlled by traffic-control signals exhibiting different colored lights, or colored lighted arrows, successively one at a time or in combination, only the colors Green, Red, and **Yellow** shall be used, except for special pedestrian signals carrying a word or legend.*

Comment: @HotLicks -- that only confirms my pre-existing opinion of Minnesota.

Comment: @Malvolio - Cute.  I'm guessing you can find similar wording in the laws of at least a dozen other states, but Minnesota's laws are reasonably well-organized and accessible so I was able to reference them quickly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Was your answer hijacked by some Bible-thumping terrorist? Why do many of the links lead to "swap me christ"? What does that have to do with "amber light"?

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw: I don't really know how that happened. It was over 10 years ago, so my memory might be ;letting me down, but it's at least *feasible* I searched for "swap me christ" around that time (as a non-standard version of "**Swipe me** Christ!). I know Google Books does/did clutter up the "current search url" with stuff relating to previous search strings that didn't get cleared out properly. I noticed that many years ago, and got into the habit of refreshing my Google Books search page before doing a final search,  to get a "clean" URL for ELU answer links...

Comment: ...but this never used to affect the validity of the actual links! All it meant was that if anyone had the rep to be able to edit my answer text themselves, they might see irrelevant text relating to previous Google Books searches in the "link" text underneath the (universally-visible) answer text itself. I can't believe I got "hacked", so I can only assume what you discovered is an artifact of the way Google Books has changed how it manages urls for repeat searches. Anyway, it's fixed now (the counts for "number of results" are probably no longer true, but I've had enough editing for now! :)

Answer (score 4):

Amber and yellow are [two different colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amber_%28color%29), technically.

Yellow is one of the CMYK primaries (0,0,100,0), while amber has a bit of magenta in it (0,25,100,0). On the color wheel yellow is at hue 30 and amber at 45. RGB values are 255,0,0 for yellow and 255,191,0 for amber.

In LCH space, which encodes perceptual brightness (L), chroma (C, richness) and hue (H), you can see that yellow is brighter than amber (L=97 vs L=81) and richer (C=86 vs C=57).

It turns out that there is a different definition of amber (SAE/ECE amber) when it comes to turning lights for cars. This amber is at RGB 255,126,0 which puts it even darker (L=66) and murkier (C=29) than the amber defined above.

There are some car lights that are strongly yellow (fog lamps). For these *selective yellow* is used.

Comment: Those really are just labels that we chose to give those parts of the spectrum though and different regions often assign the label up and down the spectrum. In addition the poster is using "light" as an example... and the subtractive CMYK model isn't usually applied to light, bur rather the additive RGB model is, instead.

Comment: Good answer - And it allowed me to have my morning coffee without having to type. I'm a former SAE committee member.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, in the US military, the status of things like communications, logistics, or tasks are referred to as Green / Amber / Red. For some reason, with that background, I call the lights on a stop light Green / Yellow / Red but any similar status updates in the civilian world I still use Green / Amber / Red.

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S. the DMV and DOT  classify the traffic light as yellow and any light on a vehicle that signals caution as amber. 
Certain instances require obtaining an 'amber light permit'

Answer (score 2):

We have [1868-2019: A Brief History of Traffic Lights](https://www.inclusivecitymaker.com/1868-2019-a-brief-history-of-traffic-lights/#:%7E:text=December%2010%2C%201868%3A%20the%20official,lit%20semaphore%20to%20ensure%20visibility.), which says that the first traffic lights were not coloured but were based on a gas-illuminated semaphore system. They were introduced in London 1868 and exploded less than two months later. This consigned them to the rubbish heap of history until…

> In 1914, red and green electric traffic lights were installed in Cleveland in the United States. Detroit and New York added **yellow** between red and green in 1920. The traffic lights that we now know were born and became the norm throughout the world.
>
> […]
>
> **Standardization and Regulation in the 1930s**
>
> The first *Convention on the Unification of Road Signals* was signed in Geneva on March 30, 1931. Its goal was to increase road traffic safety and facilitate international movement by road through a uniform system of road signals. The majority of signs that we recognize today were defined through this treaty. Traffic lights with three colors (red, **yellow**, green) became the standard.

The original *Convention on the Unification of Road Signals* is available on [a Swiss site in French, Italian and German](https://www.fedlex.admin.ch/eli/cc/50/1098_1130_1535/fr) only:

> A. **Signaux marquant une interdiction**
>
> Dans ces signaux, la couleur rouge doit prédominer nettement et faire ressortir la forme générale du signal. Les autres couleurs sont facultatives, sauf les prescriptions indiquées ci-après:
>
> a)
>
> Circulation interdite à tous véhicules: Disque rouge avec partie centrale circulaire de couleur blanche ou **jaune** clair (figure 1 du tableau II);

French, German and Italian do have the adjective and noun “amber” but

French uses “jaune” = yellow

German uses “Hellgelb” = light yellow

Italian uses “giallo chiaro” = light yellow

It is clear that, as white did not catch on, according to the convention, the colour is **yellow**, and only yellow.

The [British Highway Code was first published in 1931](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:The_Highway_Code_1931.djvu&page=5) and makes no mention of the colours of traffic lights.

The British English version of *[“The Consolidated Versions of the Vienna Convention on Road Signs and Signals, the European Agreement supplementing the Convention and its additional Protocol, Part I: Convention on Road Signs and Signals Chapter III Traffic Light Signals, Article 23, Signals for vehicular traffic](https://unece.org/DAM/trans/conventn/Conv_road_signs_2006v_EN.pdf)”* states

> An **amber** light, which shall appear alone or at the same time as the red light; when appearing alone it shall mean that no vehicle may pass the stop line or beyond the level of the signal unless it is so close to the stop line or signal when the light appears that it cannot safely be stopped before passing the stop line or beyond the level of the signal.

The USA, Canada, Australia, New Zealand and South Africa are not parties to this convention.

It thus appears that “**amber**” is a British English term and, in general, the rest of the world uses “yellow”.

Comment: ... Then there's 'Amber is a bright, warm color that is midway between yellow and orange.... Alongside red and green, amber is one the three colors seen on traffic lights, where it denotes that a driver should ‘wait’. While traffic lights are often thought to be yellow, technical guidelines in both North America and Europe actually define it as amber.' [[Canva](https://www.canva.com/colors/color-meanings/amber/)]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I’m not sure where you are getting your information from but using the search term “Technical specification for traffic lights” US sites use “yellow” - https://arlingtonva.s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2013/12/Traffic-Signal-and-Street-Light-Specifications.pdf and UK sites used “amber” 
https://www.sheffield.gov.uk/sites/default/files/docs/roads-and-pavements/guidance-for-developers/Traffic%20Signals%20Specification.pdf

Comment: In France, the law talks about “_feu jaune_” (“yellow light”) but nobody uses this in real life: it's a “_feu orange_”.

Comment: [The US Department of Energy](https://www1.eere.energy.gov/buildings/appliance_standards/standards.aspx?productid=12), [Brunel Students Union](https://brunelstudents.com/ents/event/186/), [Jerry Hicks at the LATimes](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-2001-jun-10-me-8847-story.html), [CBS News](https://www.cbsnews.com/newyork/news/sparrow-builds-nest-in-upper-east-side-traffic-light/) and [York Region, Ontario {Public Information}](https://brunelstudents.com/ents/event/186/) all seem to use 'amber'.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Project Management. You can have a RAG status (Red, Amber, Green) but in speaking terms, everyone refers to a project as being "Yellow" if certain risk/issues exist.